# Problem displaying SVG images in React Native

Tags: react-native, svg

I'm having trouble displaying an SVG image in my React Native app. When I try to display it in my React Native app, it gets distorted and doesn't look as expected.

Here is how the image should appears:

[image: Expected rendering]

And here is how it looks in my React Native app:

[image: Rendering into react native]

I've included the SVG image file that I'm using here: [file attachment]
To display the image I tried the following both method:

```js
import AltoDark from '@/assets/image/profil/alto_dark.svg';
...
<View>
//first method
<AltoDark/>
// second method
<SvgXml xml={AltoDark} />
</View>
```

my package.json is the following one

```json
 "react-native-svg": "10.1.0",
 "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
```

and my metro config is

```js
const {getDefaultConfig} = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: {sourceExts, assetExts},
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  };
})();
```

The svg file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/kPW2Qr32. Anyone suggest what might be causing this issue and how I can fix it so that the image looks correct in my React Native app?

Comment: Using Base64 image is a bad practice for SVG in react native. Replace it with svg code and your svg will work then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my svg file i change the objectBoundingBox dimension. I went from 1x1 to 2x2. Then I played with the before last argument of the transform="matrix()" to adjust the horizontal position of the image. I went from `0.160427`to `0.760427`

```
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0_595_4081" transform="matrix(0.00191705 0 0 0.000715206 0.160427 0.0851681)"/>
</pattern>
```

```
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="2" height="2">
<use xlink:href="#image0_595_4081" transform="matrix(0.00191705 0 0 0.000715206 0.760427 0.0851681)"/>
</pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

I follow the below steps while using an SVG image in React Native app.

1. Convert SVG to JSX element from [here](https://svg2jsx.com/).
2. Create a .tsx file and paste the JSX element.
3. Give a desirable name & export the JSX element as a functional component.
4. Use it like this in your component.

```
import AltoDark from '../../components';

...
...


<AltoDark/>
```